# Why do airlines often serve a small dry snack shortly before a larger meal?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, in-flight-services

On long flights, I'm often given a very small bag of some kind of dried snack shortly (10-15 minutes) before a main meal is served - e.g. on a flight I was on yesterday, passengers were given a 10g bag of pretzels.

I'm wondering if this has some purpose beyond nutrition - e.g. to get people's digestion working and make the meal more comfortable / reduce competition for the facilities immediately after the meal?

Comment: Which airline is that? not sure this is something most airline do

Comment: @NeanDerThal Alaska Airlines did this on the flight I was on. They took orders for meals while giving out drinks and snacks, and handed out meals directly afterwards. It was more than ten minutes, but I could see it being that short if the flight wasn't very full or big, maybe.

Comment: Most Asian airlines (non-Low-cost anyway) do that too.

Comment: Was the snack handed out as part of the pre-meal drinks service?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yesterday not directly with the drink, though there may have been a drink served shortly before.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**It's meant to go with your pre-dinner drink.** Better airlines still do a drinks run before they start the dinner service, so the pretzels/peanuts/etc are meant to accompany the drink, particularly if alcoholic.

Of course, a number of airlines now charge for drinks or have cut them out entirely, making this a bit of a vestigial appendix.

Comment: Is there any other kind of appendix?

Comment: Perhaps it is an appendicinal vestige?

Comment: @aroth sections at the end of a book which are not key to the book's main content, but a related are often called appendices, but they aren't vestigial

Comment: @aroth one in other animals (assuming human one is vestigial as this is not certain AFAIK)?